# Submitting Parent Form But Child form Is not Submitting

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a parent form as  and this form contain 5 more form on my five tabs. The problem is when i submit my parent form the data on parent form is submitting but all child form is not going on server. As i think by submitting parent form all child form are ignored. if i am right then please suggest a solution for this problem. i be very thankfull to all of you guys.I am using jsf2.0 primefaces 3.4

---

I have some problems in my page after merging the parent and children forms into a single one. I cannot update the `<h:textarea>` on row selection event.suggest me where i am wrong on update event my code is below

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <h:panelGrid>
    <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="#{salesLetterProBean.activeIndex}">
        <p:tab title="Product Introduction" id="productinfooTab">
            <p:panel header="Please Fill In The Details" style="padding:5px;"
                id="productInfoPanel">
                <h:panelGrid  cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" columns="1"
                    columnClasses="a,b,c,d,e" rowClasses="plainRow,shadedRow">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Introductory HeadLine:" class="field-title"
                        id="proInfoPanelGrid"/>
                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{salesLetterProBean.productIntroductoryLineRow.description}"
                        id="proIntroductorySentence"
                        style="width:1060px;height:400px;" effectDuration="400" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:dataTable var="productIntroSentenceList" first="1"
                    value="#{salesLetterProBean.productIntroductorySentenceList}"
                    paginator="true" rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25"
                    rowIndexVar="rowIndex" rowKey="#{productIntroSentenceList.id}"
                    selection="#{salesLetterProBean.productIntroductoryLineRow}"
                    selectionMode="single" update="proIntroductorySentence">
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{salesLetterProBean.onRowSelect}" />
                    <p:column headerText="#">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{rowIndex}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Description">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{productIntroSentenceList.description}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{productIntroSentenceList.description}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Select">
                        <p:commandLink process="@none">
                            <!--  -->
                            <span title="Select" class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"/>
                        </p:commandLink>        
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <h:panelGrid cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" columns="1"
                    columnClasses="a,b,c,d,e" rowClasses="plainRow,shadedRow">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Feature List:" class="field-title" />
                    <p:inputTextarea style="width:1060px;height:400px;"
                        effectDuration="400" id="featureList"
                        value="#{salesLetterProBean.featureList}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="How Your Product Solve The Problems :"
                        class="field-title" />
                    <p:inputTextarea style="width:1060px;height:400px;"
                        effectDuration="400" id="prbSolutions"
                        value="#{salesLetterProBean.problemSolutions}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:commandButton value="Previous"
                    actionListener="#{applicantManagedBean.changeActiveIndex}"
                    immediate="true" class="defaultButton" />
                <h:commandButton value="   Next   "
                    actionListener="#{applicantManagedBean.changeActiveIndex}"
                    immediate="true" class="defaultButton" />
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel> 
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Regards.

Comment: You can't nest `<h:form>`, maybe you have 6 forms and the action is being executed only for 1 form (what you call the *parent* one), that's how Web Apps work. If you want to *submit more than 1 form* you need to wrap all your forms into a single one instead of splitting it in 2 or more forms.

Comment: Hi thanks fro reply Luiggi. But the problem is that i cant remove the rest of forms. Is there any way using jquery so that i can get the value for other forms controll like my second form has input text user name. i want this value on backing beans by submitting my parent form which contain all rest of form. because i am now stuck with this as i cannot wrap all the data in one form.please reply

Comment: If that's what you need (very odd) then you need at least one `<h:inputHidden>` for every UIInput component in your other forms and use jquery or other tool to pass the data from every form into every `<h:inputHidden>` (lot of hard work). Take note that this behavior can't be solved using another MVC framework because the *problem* is result of web application common behavior. The best would be to have a single form that wraps all the data. If you have other actions/ajax requests inside these forms, you can use `execute` tag attribute to limit the components to send to server.

Comment: hmmm thanks let me try some other stuff and the only problem is i uses datatable of prime facs and on row selection i am updating some text area. if i remove the child form from those datatable and update the text controll only (as currently i am updating whole child from) may be i get rid of this problem

Comment: HI Luiggi can you have a look on my code i cannot get update the text area on row selection event.suggest me where i am wrong on update event my code is below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215267/submittng-a-child-form-in-a-nested-form-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

nested forms are not allowed, but you can have a multiple forms as stack.